# javascript Type error innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Im writing a code and im getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" error

html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src ="timer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="r"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Script

```
//window.onload=function(){
var start=Date.now(),r=document.getElementById('r');
(function f(){
var diff=Date.now()-start,ns=(((3e5-diff)/1000)>>0),m=(ns/60)>>0,s=ns-m*60;
r.textContent="Registration closes in "+m+':'+((''+s).length>1?'':'0')+s+' 
minutes';
document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = result;
if(diff>(3e5)){start=Date.now()}
setTimeout(f,1000);
})();
//}
```

I just want to display the result on the html page

Comment: I dont see an element with an id of "test" in your html?

Comment: I have edited the code, to reflect the correct code

Comment: well you reference the element before it exists....

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with id = 'test'

I think you have to write:

```
(function f() {
    var start = Date.now(),
    var r = document.getElementById('r');
    var diff = Date.now() - start,
        ns = (((3e5 - diff) / 1000) >> 0),
        m = (ns / 60) >> 0,
        s = ns - m * 60;
    r.textContent = "Registration closes in " + m + ':' + (('' + s).length > 1 ? '' : '0') + s + ' minutes';
    //here the change
    document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = result;
    if (diff > (3e5)) {
        start = Date.now()
    }
    setTimeout(f, 1000);
})();
```

And please use Javascript indentation.

Comment: Don't forget to add the correct code

Comment: I have edited the code to reflect the correct code

Comment: I am still getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null. referring to r.textContent line

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null is the error its referencing still on the r.textContent line

Comment: I know it but now it works

Comment: which browser are you using. the edited code is not working for me